# Create a new stencil from a master shape in Visio 2013 Professional

Tags: visio

I am trying so hard to make a stencil in Visio 2013 Professional based off of one of the master stencils. The Microsoft website says this is possible but I'm starting to have serious doubts.

[Create, Save, and Share Custom Stencils](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-save-and-share-custom-stencils-HA102749233.aspx)
[Edit a Master Shape](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/edit-a-master-shape-HA102749205.aspx)

I am making UML diagrams. What I want is a dashed line ala the "Interface Realization" or "Dependency" association found in the UML Class category, but I want it without the arrowhead. This is what I have been doing to try and make that happen:

1. Right click on "Interface Realization" -> Add to MyShapes -> Add to New Stencil -> Save 'Stencil1'
2. Left click on More Shapes -> MyShapes -> 'Stencil1'
3. Right click on 'Stencil1' (now open in the Shapes browser) -> Edit Stencil
4. Right click on "Interface Realization" -> Edit Master -> Edit Master Shape
5. Right click on the shape in the new window -> Format Shape
6. Left click on Line -> End Arrow Type -> #00: None

WOOPS! SORRY SIR LOOKS LIKE YOU CANT DO THAT! BACK TO #14: Open Ended Arrow FOR YOU!!

This is so, incredibly, frustrating. What do I do in order to get Visio to save my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape is designed to prevent easily changing this property, so you need to brute-force your way through this.  Open up the master's shapesheet and change the LineFormat/EndArrow cell formula to 0 (or GUARD(0) if you prefer).